# Select only selected check_boxes using check_box_tag in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `each` loop which creates a set of checkboxes.

Controller code is

```
  def new
    @foo = Foo.new
    @books = Book.all
  end

  def edit
    @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
    @books = Book.all
  end
```

Erb file looks like the following:

```
<div>
  <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'books[]', book.id, (checked = true if @books.collect{|b| b.id}.include?(book.id)) %>
    <%= book.name %><br />
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here am trying to show only the selected check_box values when i edit my page. But in my case it selecting all values even some of the checkboxes are unselected. So How to select only a checked values using check_box_tag in rails?

Answer (score 0):

```
... @books.each do |book|
... if @books.collect{|b| b.id}.include?(book.id))
```

This condition is always true. `@books` will always contain `book` and its `id`.

Minor corrections: you don't need local var `checked` there. Instead of `map`/`include`, you should uze `any?`.

```
<%= check_box_tag 'books[]', book.id, @books.any?{|b| b.id == book.id} %>
```

**Note**: the condition is still always true. Maybe you've oversimplified code, when preparing for the question, and omitted important parts.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! yes, the above code is still selecting all the check_boxes. The condition is still true like as you said ! So, Is there a different way to handle this problem ?

Comment: @diya: yes, modify the condition. How do you store data about selected checkboxes? Use that knowledge.

Comment: What if @books is nil? it is going to break.